# Casting Using ArrayList Under .NET4.5

Tags: c#, casting, arraylist, .net-4.5

All I have a utility method that is defined as

```
public static Dictionary<T, int> CountOccurences<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) { ... }
```

I have some legacy code that unfortunately uses `ArrayList`s instead of `List<T>`. Now, I need to cast the `ArrayList` to use the above method and both of the following *should* work

```
var v = CountOccurences<String>(arrayList.Cast<String>().ToArray());
```

or

```
var v = CountOccurences<String>(arrayList.OfType<String>().ToArray());
```

Neither of these work in VS2012 under .NET 4.5 giving

> 'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, I have tested this in LINQpad and they *both* work. **Why can't I cast my `ArrayList`?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: arrayList.Cast<String>() is an IEnumerable<String>, you don't need to call ToArray

Comment: Without the actual error message I can only guess, but are you using the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: hmm just tried it, it doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Absolute stupidity on my part. Missing reference to `Linq`. Sorry boys... I hang my head in shame :[.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works fine for me in VS2012

```
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        al.Add("a");
        al.Add("b");
        al.Add("c");

        var v = al.OfType<string>().ToArray();

        var list = new List<string>(v); //Constructor taking an IEnumerable<string>();
```

What error message are you receiving.

Make sure you are including the following namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that "not work" means that you get an `InvalidCastException`. So not all objects in the `ArrayList` are strings. You could circumvent the problem by creating a new non-generic overload of `CountOccurences` which takes an `ArrayList`:

(presuming the functionality of the method)

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> CountOccurences(ArrayList items) 
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach(object t in items)
    {
        string key = "";
        if(t != null)
            key = t.ToString();
        int count;
        dict.TryGetValue(key, out count);
        dict[key] = count++;
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't throw any errors in my case:

BTW, your usage of `OfType<T>` is wrong. It's a method, so append `()`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _16853758
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

            var a = CountOccurences<String>(arrayList.Cast<String>().ToArray());
            var v = CountOccurences<String>(arrayList.OfType<String>().ToArray());
        }

        public static Dictionary<T, int> CountOccurences<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) { return new Dictionary<T, int>(); }
    }
}
```